# Display HTML form values in same page after submit using Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a HTML form and I need to display the form field values below the form after user clicks the submit button. How can I do this using HTML and JavaScript Ajax?

Comment: @Iesus: Of course you can. Bind a submit handler to the form, read the values, modify the DOM, send the data via Ajax.

Comment: @FelixKling, Didnt think of that. It would actually work. Perhaps a little bit over this guys level but it would work ^^. You could even make it simpler, like posting the data with a target frame/window (or iframe) and fetch the data onsubmit

Comment: @FelixKling What's the problem with HTML,Javascript. He can do it client side too. If he doesnt need do anything with the values,or post it anywhere. But just edit the HTML content.

Comment: @optim: Did you mean to address Iesus? I never said there is any problem...

Comment: @FelixKling oh sorry then.but we dont need Ajax too.Right? What it seems he wants to do is just edit HTML content.

Comment: @optim: No, of course you don't need it. I just laid out how the workflow would be if one wants preserve the normal functionality of the form. The question contains so little information, anything beyond reading form value and manipulation of the DOM is just guessing anyway.

Answer (score 32):

Here is one way to do it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script language="JavaScript">
    function showInput() {
        document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = 
                    document.getElementById("user_input").value;
    }
  </script>

  </head>
<body>

  <form>
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is what it looks like when run.Cheers.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

One more way to do it (if you use form), note that input type is button

```
<input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
```

Complete code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML JavaScript output on same page</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function showMessage(){
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            display_message.innerHTML= message;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
Enter message: <input type="text" id = "message">
<input type="button" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
</form>
<p> Message is: <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

But you can do it even without form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML JavaScript output on same page</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        function showMessage(){
            var message = document.getElementById("message").value;
            display_message.innerHTML= message;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
Enter message: <input type="text" id = "message">
<input type="submit" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
<p> Message is: <span id = "display_message"></span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can use either submit or button:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="showMessage()" value="submit" />
```

No need to set

```
return false;
```

from JavaScript function for neither of those two examples.

Comment: This is the kind of answer it would be good to see more of on this platform! Nice work!

Answer (score 2):

This works.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
function write_below(form)
{
var input = document.forms.write.input_to_write.value;
document.getElementById('write_here').innerHTML="Your input was:"+input;
return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<!--Insert more code here-->
<body>
<form name='write' onsubmit='return write_below(this);'>
<input type = "text" name='input_to_write'>
<input type = "button" value = "submit" />
</form>
<div id='write_here'></div></body>
</html>
```

Returning false from the function never posts it to other page,but does edit the html content.

Comment: no this doesn't works! I tried it today and it didn't worked!

Comment: @user2567857 It works. I too have tried it. Why don't you start a new thread of what you tried, and share a link here.

Answer (score 2):

```js
var tasks = [];
var descs = [];

// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
var rowCount = 1;

function addTasks() {
  var temp = 'style .fa fa-trash';
  tasks.push(document.getElementById("taskname").value);
  descs.push(document.getElementById("taskdesc").value);
  var table = document.getElementById("tasksTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
  cell1.innerHTML = tasks[rowCount - 1];
  cell2.innerHTML = descs[rowCount - 1];
  cell3.innerHTML = getDate();
  cell4.innerHTML = '<td class="fa fa-trash"></td>';
  rowCount++;
  modal.style.display = "none";
}


function getDate() {
  var today = new Date();
  var dd = today.getDate();
  var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!

  var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

  if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd;
  }
  if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm;
  }
  var today = dd + '-' + mm + '-' + yyyy.toString().slice(2);
  return today;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
  <div style="background-color:#0F0F8C ;height:45px">
    <h2 style="color: white">LOGO</h2>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button id="myBtn">&emsp;+ Add Task &emsp;</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <table id="tasksTable">
      <thead>
        <tr style="background-color:rgba(201, 196, 196, 0.86)">
          <th style="width: 150px;">Name</th>
          <th style="width: 250px;">Desc</th>
          <th style="width: 120px">Date</th>
          <th style="width: 120px class=fa fa-trash"></th>
        </tr>

      </thead>
      <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">

    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">

        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <h3> Add Task</h3>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-body">
        <table style="padding: 28px 50px">
          <tr>
            <td style="width:150px">Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="taskname" style="width: -webkit-fill-available"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
              Desc:
            </td>
            <td>
              <textarea name="desc" id="taskdesc" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="submit" value="submit" style="float: right;" onclick="addTasks()">SUBMIT</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function get_values(input_id)
{
var input = document.getElementById(input_id).value;
document.write(input);
}
</script>

<!--Insert more code here-->


<input type = "text" id = "textfield">
<input type = "button" onclick = "get('textfield')" value = "submit">
```

Next time you ask a question here, include more detail and what you have tried.

Comment: Next time you answer a question here, include some details about what the code does.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
onsubmit="return f(this.'yourfieldname'.value);"
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: What is `f`? What is `onsubmit="..."`? Where does it go in the code? This is a very simplistic example. Assuming that the OP is new to JavaScript, I don't see how this is very helpful. Please *explain* your code at least.

Answer (score -2):

display html form values in same page after clicking on submit button using JS & html codes. After opening it up again it should give that comments in that page.

Comment: Could you be more elaborate?

Comment: This is not a SO quality answer