# Display submitted form data on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am trying to display what is typed and submitted in my form, on the same page. I got the first entry "name" to display, but can't get the rest to show up. I am using JQuery validator. I feel like it's something simple I am missing here. Thanks!

Script:

```
$(function() {
    $("#signup").validate();

    $("#signup").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var display = 

        $("#name").val();
        $("#theage").val();
        $("#theemail").val();           


        $("#result").html(display);
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div>
    <form id="signup">
        <label for="name" class="label">Enter your name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Required" class="required">&nbsp;

        <label for="theage" class="label">Enter your age</label>
        <input type="text" name="theage" id="theage" title="Required" class="required digits">&nbsp;

        <label for="theemail" class="label">Enter your email</label>
        <input type="text" name="theemail" id="theemail" title="Please enter a valid email address" class="required email">&nbsp;

        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name="submit" id='submitme'>
    </form>

    <p> Your name: </p>
    <p> Age: </p>
    <p> Email: </p>
    <p id="result"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: With a little bit of Google you could get here. Check it [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447889/display-html-form-values-in-same-page-after-submit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447889/display-html-form-values-in-same-page-after-submit)

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate the form values. Right now, you're only adding the `name` to your `display` var.

```
var display = 
    $("#name").val(); // statement ends here because of semicolon
    $("#theage").val();
    $("#theemail").val();
```

needs to change to

```
var display = 
    $("#name").val() + " " +
    $("#theage").val() + " " +
    $("#theemail").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is because you are only adding $("#name").val() to the display variable, You need to concatenate them.

```
var display = $("#name").val() + " " +
              $("#theage").val() + " " + 
              $("#theemail").val();
```

Here's an example:

```js
var result =
            "Hello "; // semi colon ends the assignment
            "world"; // this is doing nothing

$('#result1').html(result);


var result2 =
             "Hello " +
             "world";

$('#result2').html(result2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
1:
<div id="result1"></div>
<br> 2:
<div id="result2"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not throwing in console, you were missing plugins.

```js
$(function() {

        $("#signup").validate();

        $("#signup").submit(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var display = 

            $("#name").val();
            $("#theage").val();
            $("#theemail").val();           


            $("#result").html(display);

        });

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <form id="signup">

        <label for="name" class="label">Enter your name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" title="Required" class="required">&nbsp;



        <label for="theage" class="label">Enter your age</label>
        <input type="text" name="theage" id="theage" title="Required"  class="required digits">&nbsp;



        <label for="theemail" class="label">Enter your email</label>
        <input type="text" name="theemail" id="theemail" title="Please enter a valid email address" class="required email">&nbsp;

        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name="submit" id='submitme'>

    </form>
    <p> Your name: </p>
    <p> Age: </p>
    <p> Email: </p>
    <p id="result"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: The OP wasn't asking about validation plugins, it was about why the display variable is not picking up all 3 values.

Comment: I didn't even look at that basic code, I thought he is aware of basic. But I agree with you Brad.

Answer (score 0):

To display the values entered on the form you could use the following:

```
$(function() {
    $("#signup").validate();

    $("#signup").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var display = "<p>Your name: " + $("#name").val() + "</p><p>Your age: " + $("#theage").val() + "</p><p>Your email: " + $("#theemail").val() + "</p>";

        $("#result").html(display);
    });
});
```

Comment: This helped, needed to concatenate the values.