# How do I show the message of the input box after submitting my form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, forms, django-forms

I am building a form. And I wish to keep the input value visible after submitting the form. I followed some instructions online to use the showMessage() function, however, it's not working for me.

```
<form id = "form1" action="." method="POST">{% csrf_token %}      
  <div class=".col1" style="float:left;vertical-align: middle;">            
    {{ form.region }}
    {{ form.operator }}
  </div>
  <div id = "form1_value" class="col-xs-2 style="vertical-align: middle;">
    {{ form.value }}
  </div>    
</form>
<div>
  <input type="button" class = "btn" value="Run" onclick="SubmitForm1(), showMessage()"/>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no way to really do that efficiently with javascript *(cookies, localstorage etc. isn't really a good way to do that)*. If you want to keep the value after the form submits, and the page reloads, you'd do it with serverside code

Comment: The page will reload, if you submit without AJAX.

Comment: What's your backend? Django?

Comment: You mean `SubmitForm1(); showMessage()` with a `;`?

Comment: @Miro yea. it's based on built from Django

Comment: @dickli2119 did my answer help you somehow or you simply don't care anymore? Did another Problem appear? Please don't leave questions like this!

Answer (score 0):

Your `onclick` function should read `SubmitForm1()`, which should make an AJAX request, which is *greatly* simplified using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: ".", // from the action attribute of your <form>
    data: {
        key1: value1,
        key2: value2
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        // event handler for when submission is complete
    }
}
```

Code adapted from [here](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/getpost-with-ajax).

This will NOT reload the page or load a new page. You might want to set `disabled = true` as an attribute of your `<input type="button"...` on the button to prevent re-clicking the form submit button.

Edit: note that this answer was being written before OP noted that Django is the project's backend, but is left here in hopes that it benefits someone asking a similar question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, after I typed in my longer answer on this earlier, just realized that you wanted to solve this with only using javascript or jquery. In that case you can just create your Form in the HTML page(not with Django Form, it depends on how complex the form is) and you can use a short script function to show the input data of the Form.

So, the HTML would look something like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  function showInput() {
      document.getElementById('display').innerHTML =
                  document.getElementById("user_input").value;
  }
</script>

<div class="">
  <form method:"post">
  {% csrf_token %}
    <label><b>Enter a Message</b></label>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="user_input">
  </form>

  <input type="submit" onclick="showInput();"><br/>
  <label>Your input: </label>
  <p><span id='display'></span></p>
</div>
```

This javascript solution was already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15447889/display-html-form-values-in-same-page-after-submit) to another similar question by another user. I just wanted to repeat it and mention that you can use the same thing even if you use Django for the back end. In Django views.py you can also handle/save the submitted objects/data from this Form with a view function.

And if you want to use Django created Forms, then you can also identify all the fields of the Form by HTML fields' id which you want to show after submission. Django create id for fields like: "id_message", depending on the field name. You can use getElementById on them too and can use the above function on them.